# psr4 autoload class not found

Tags: php, composer-php, psr-4

I am making my own framework but I have a problem with psr4 autoload and composer.
I can not make classes available and apparently everything is fine
This is the error, I don't want to use include for class files:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'System\Template\get_template_files_class' not found in /var/www/html/fsib/system/layout-compiler.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/fsib/system/layout-compiler.php on line 7
```

> composer.json

```
{
"require": {
    "illuminate/database": "*",
    "illuminate/routing": "~5.1.16",
    "illuminate/events": "~5.1.16"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
       "System\\" : "system/libs/"
     }
}}
```

> layout-compiler.php

```
<?php

 require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

 use System\Template\get_template_files_class;

 $templates = new get_template_files_class;

 ?>
```

> get_templates_files_class.php

```
<?php 

namespace System\Template

  class get_template_files_class {

  }

?>
```

Comment: Please add the relative paths to the file names - probably they are not correct. And have you used `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: yes i use composer dump-autoload

Comment: And what about the absolute file paths?

Comment: Write `require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';`. Note the leading slash too! Any change?

Comment: And you forgot the semicolon (;) after `namespace System\Template`.

Comment: @aendeerei (;) after namestpace System\Template is the problem and tthe way that i use the classs  use System\Template\get_template_files_class;

Comment: thanks to all the problem is fixed

Comment: Good to know ;-)